# What is the greatest common divisor of $11+i$ and $1+3i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

What is the greatest common divisor of $11+i$ and $1+3i$? Or in general, how can we solve problems like this?

Comment: I've tried the Euclidean Algorithm but it doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: Gaussian integers have unique facorizations... Can you try to factor these numbers?

Comment: Oh i see... So is the answer 1+i?

Comment: Or $1-i$, which is the same answer, since one is a unit times the other.

Comment: Got ya. Thanks!

Comment: You might help your Readers by specifying that the context of "divisors" is the ring of Gaussian integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and guess the factorization of $1+3i$; since
$$
(1+3i)(1-3i)=1+9=10=2\cdot 5
$$
the only candidates for being a prime factor are $1+i$, $2+i$ and $2-i$. Note that $1+i$ certainly divides both $1+3i$ and $1-3i$ (its conjugate is an associate).

Similarly,
$$
(11+i)(11-i)=122=2\cdot 61
$$
so the only candidates are $1+i$, $6+5i$ and $6-5i$. The same argument as before applies.